# Python - Matrix with the sum of two variable depending on a third

Tags: python, matrix, pivot, heatmap

I'm trying to analyze the evolution of two variables in funtion of a thresholds.
I start from a dataframe like:

```
list1 = [[0,6,3], [100,6,1], [200,4,1], [300,3,0], [400,3,0], [500,0,0]]
cols = ['threshold', 'var_1', 'var_2']
raw = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=cols)
raw.head()


threshold   var_1   var_2
     0        6       3
   100        6       1
   200        4       1
   300        3       0
   400        3       0
```

And the goal is to represente the sum of both vars deppending on the threshold like this, to use in a heatmap:

```
            500 3   1   1   0   0   0
            400 5   3   3   2   2   2
    var_1   300 6   4   4   3   3   3
            200 7   5   5   4   4   4
            100 9   7   7   6   6   6
              0 9   7   7   6   6   6
                0   100 200 300 400 500
                          var_2
```

I've tried  corrstab, and pivot_table but I don't get this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around Pandas documentation, I also could not find any built-in function providing the result you showed. There is one homemade solution that might work for you; it relies on an iterator formed using Python's [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to represent all the combinations of the two variables.

This solution is not optimized, because for larger-scale data this iterator would be slower than the built-ins from Numpy and Pandas. For a matrix of your size, though, it should still be pretty fast.

```py
list1 = [[0,6,3], [100,6,1], [200,4,1], [300,3,0], [400,3,0], [500,0,0]]
cols = ['threshold', 'var_1', 'var_2']
raw = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=cols)
nrows = len(raw.index)
combos = itertools.product(range(nrows), range(nrows))
heatmap = np.zeros((nrows + 1, nrows + 1))
heatmap[:-1, 0] = np.flip(raw['threshold'])
heatmap[-1, 1:] = raw['threshold']
for combo in combos:
  heatmap[heatmap.shape[0] - combo[0] - 2, combo[1] + 1] =\
    raw['var_1'][combo[0]] + raw['var_2'][combo[1]]
print(heatmap)
```

```
[[500.   3.   1.   1.   0.   0.   0.]
 [400.   6.   4.   4.   3.   3.   3.]
 [300.   6.   4.   4.   3.   3.   3.]
 [200.   7.   5.   5.   4.   4.   4.]
 [100.   9.   7.   7.   6.   6.   6.]
 [  0.   9.   7.   7.   6.   6.   6.]
 [  0.   0. 100. 200. 300. 400. 500.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I've solved it in a similar manner because I can not find any built-in method. One more time many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I came up with.  Seems it is efficient as well
I came to this soln after a pattern study

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

list1 = [[0,6,3], [100,6,1], [200,4,1], [300,3,0], [400,3,0], [500,0,0]]
cols = ['threshold', 'var_1', 'var_2']
raw = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=cols)

for i, col_name in enumerate(raw['threshold'].values):
    raw[col_name] = raw.iloc[i,2] + raw.iloc[:,1]

print(raw)
```

Output:

```
   threshold  var_1  var_2  0  100  200  300  400  500
0          0      6      3  9    7    7    6    6    6
1        100      6      1  9    7    7    6    6    6
2        200      4      1  7    5    5    4    4    4
3        300      3      0  6    4    4    3    3    3
4        400      3      0  6    4    4    3    3    3
5        500      0      0  3    1    1    0    0    0
```